# Java - PDFBox - PDF with JBIG2 image

Tags: java, image, pdf, pdfbox, jbig2

I'm getting a problem using PDFBox API.
I have a PDF file with a JBIG2 image in it and I want to read it out and create a JPEG or PNG file with the PDF content.
Unfortunately I'm only getting a black image.

My code is:

```
public static void copyDocumentAsImage(String path) throws IOException {
        PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File(path));
        String destinationDir = "myDestinationPath";
        BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(2000, 2000, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
        PDXObjectImage ximage = new PDJpeg(document, img);
        ximage.write2file(destinationDir);
}
```

I already checked this: https://issues.apache.org/jira/i#browse/PDFBOX-1067
But it did not work for me or I not getting the right solution.

Can someone help me out with it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you link pdf file.

Comment: There is a possibly related issue that I am working on here:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-2026

Answer (score 3):

JBIG2 images are handled by an optional extension, that probably it isn't supplied by you:

Reading JBIG2 images: JBIG2 ImageIO or JBIG2-Image-Decoder

Just load this dependency from Maven:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.levigo.jbig2</groupId>
  <artifactId>levigo-jbig2-imageio</artifactId>
  <version>1.6.5</version>
</dependency>
```

[More information here](https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/dependencies.html).

Comment: Update: it seems the preferred dependency is now
`org.apache.pdfbox:jbig2-imageio` with version `3.0.4` being the latest at the time of writing this comment.